# Install pycurl on Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, pycurl

After hours of reading on the internet I found the easiest solution to install pycurl on mac os x.
Make sure you have Xcode UNIX tool installed  and run this command.

sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" easy_install setuptools pycurl==7.16.2.1

Comment: You should flag your own question as answered?

Comment: you have any idea how to isntall pycurl using PIP instead?

Comment: For i386 architecture machines it should be, sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" easy_install setuptools pycurl==7.16.2.1

Comment: Exactly answered my question. +1

Comment: Mickey, pip is just: sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install pycurl==7.16.2.1